# Ruby on Rails: How do I add a confirmation to a submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete" , :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected?' %>
```

doesn't work.

how do I do this?

Comment: what error it gives to you?it works for me

Comment: actuallyyy .the problem is this, (discovered with chrome) prototype.js:3483Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Most likely you didn't include necessary JavaScript files. Do you have something like this in your HTML head tag?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected?' }%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution and it works to me.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save', onclick: "return confirm('Are you sure?')" %>
```

The Solution link is
[Here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/how-can-i-add-a-confirmation-dialog-to-a-submit-tag/113767)

Thanks